# Girth of Kneser graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What is known about the girth of Kneser graphs?
For $n,k$ positive integers such that $n\geq 2k$, the *Kneser graph* of parameters $n,k$ is defined as the graph whose vertex set is the set of all $k$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and two such subsets are adjacent if and only if they are disjoint. I wonder if an explicit formula, or a bound, for the girth of such graphs is known.

Comment: A bit of thinking will tell you that the girth is either $3$ or $4$ if $n \ge 2k+2$, and the remaining case is handled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728539/prove-that-odd-graph-has-girth-of-6?rq=1).